# Executing commands server-side & client-side in Java

Tags: java, php, client-side, server-side

I'm stumbling on what is the proper way is to execute a simple CLI command. I see I can do it in PHP, but I would prefer a Java solution if possible.

Need to do one on the server end, and another on the client end. Example:

```
openvpn "C:\someDir\test.ovpn"
```

The applet is signed and has full access client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Runtime.getRuntime() :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openvpn \"C:\\someDir\\test.ovpn\"");
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question.  This should work on server side either. Maybe you wish to launch that via a web page hosted on the server.  In that case, you can do that with a servlet, in a web server like tomcat.

Comment: I'll have to look into setting up a servlet in that case.

I am running into a bit of an issue, openVPN requires elevated privileges due to it needing to make changes to the routes on a computer.

How best would I go about running that same command but elevated so as to successfully bridge a VPN connection?

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure.  Maybe running the web server (ex tomcat) with the required privileges on the os ?  You'll need to secure your application.